# MVC4 jquery how to post multidimensional data to mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I've MVC4 application
a Controller with a method which takes, a parameter, a list.

```
public ActionResult Save(List<PRICING_PERIOD_ext> pricing_period_list)
```

I need to call this method with jquery post (clientside)

```
  $.post("/PricingPeriodTest/Save",
           { pricing_period_list: dati },
            function (data) {

                });
```

What is the best way to pass parameter?
At the moment I'm filling via javascript data like this

```
{ID_PRICING_PERIOD:1,DATA_START:01/01/2013 00:00:00,DATA_END:31/01/2013 00:00:00,FLAG_OP_ON_SAVE:},
{ID_PRICING_PERIOD:2,DATA_START:01/05/2013 00:00:00,DATA_END:31/05/2013 00:00:00,FLAG_OP_ON_SAVE:}
```

But it doens't work..
In a case like this how do you pass parameter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try to change list to array like so :

```
public ActionResult Save(PRICING_PERIOD_ext[] pricing_period_list)
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me PRICING_PERIOD_ext[] instead of List<PRICING_PERIOD_ext> but i was focusing on data instead of controller, so thank you for the suggestion

Comment: You should have a class on server side that will be interpreted by the controller. Then on your client side, you should make a js object having the same properties as the .NET object case sensitive and send it as json data.

Comment: @Bart That's the overall theory, but there is a specific format to use when ModelBinding collections.  tereško, I know how to do it with a form post, but haven't yet tried ModelBinding collections via AJAX.  If I get a chance I will get some code working and post it here.

Comment: .NET will try to deserialize the object to the specified class. If can do it, there's nothing different from normal form as opposed to ajax post regarding on binding at controller level.